# count of characters in string where for non adjacent characters count should be different

Tags: python

'count of characters in the string where for nonadjacent characters count should be different.'

Given a String:

```
      'aabbcdab'
```

output should be as :

```
       a:2
       b:2
       c:1
       d:1
       a:1
       b:1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? A good place to start is by iterating through your string and seeing what you get (ex. do `for x in myString` and see what `x` is). Then you need a way to keep track of which letter you're "counting" and what the count is at that point

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
s = "aaabbaabbb"
last_char = ''
count = 0
for c in s:
    if c == last_char:
        count += 1
        continue
    if count > 1:
        print(last_char + ":" + str(count))
    count = 1
    last_char = c
       
print(last_char + ":" + str(count))
```

Output:

```
a:3
b:2
a:2
b:3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is why we have [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'aabbcdab'
for k, g in groupby(s):
    print(f'{k}:{len(list(g))}')
```

prints:

```
a:2
b:2
c:1
d:1
a:1
b:1
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark. It worked :). I was not aware of this function!

Comment: Yeah @Pradeep all of itertools is very useful! It’s worth spending some time to learn.